# python / sqlite3 - Which is the process writing the file?

Tags: python, shell, sqlite, insert, edit

If I build a database using sqlite3 from within python, what will be the process called that edits the database file?

Will I be able to notice from shell that a database is not closed - even if no inserts are currently being committed?

Comment: So if I check `lsof -c python -- $database`, it will tell me wether the python process has finished working on the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is an *embedded* database, so there is no separate process.

You can check with `lsof` or similar tools whether the Python process has an open handle to the database file. However, such a handle corresponds to an open connection; it does not tell you whether there is an active transaction.

A transaction locks the DB file; you can try to check for that with `lslk` or `lslocks`. But if you actually want to do something with the DB, it might be a better idea to use the synchronization mechanisms of SQLite itself, and to try to execute [BEGIN EXCLUSIVE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).

Comment: Great, I was just going to specify my question as to whether lsof will show the file as open between python lines `conn=sqlite3.connect('database.db')` and `conn.close()`.